# Is a gradual 3/4 inch rise acceptable under carpet?

Tags: subfloor, carpet

I have a change in subfloor height to contend with. For whatever reason at one doorway of the house the subfloor was built 3/4" (19 mm) higher than the neighboring section.

I can install a tapered board here so that the rise would take place over about a 5" (125 mm) run. However with carpet over this I am concerned it *may not be visible enough and could be a trip hazard.*

Any tips on whether this is really a concern and if so what to do about it?

---

There is no practical way to alter the construction to get all the subfloor in the same plane. But I might be able to extend the run of the transition to about 10" with some localized alterations to the subfloor just at this doorway. The doorway is through a 10" thick wall.

Comment: a 10" long slope that's near invisible will pose a trip hazard, you're better to leave the step and mark it with some contrasting colour,

Comment: @Jasen that is the kind of concern I have as well. I was thinking perhaps a metal carpet strip placed just to draw attention might be worthwhile. I'm also curious if this sort of thing is covered in any building regulations / building codes - even if not local to me - just to learn more about what are the best practices.

Answer (score 5):

There are shims made for these situations. Have a look

[image]

[These are made by traxx.](https://www.traxxcorp.com/products/traxx-ramps/carpet-shims/) Ask at your local carpet shop or order on line

If you take a look at the link you will see a variety of options including one shim that is 24” in the ramp from 0-1”. 
 In my opinion this is a good fix for a transition like yours and is easy to walk across.
You can of course ask your local AHJ about code compliance.

Comment: This may be a convenient way to construct the slope that is needed, thanks. But it doesn't really address the core question of whether this rise is a concern or if I should go to extra effort to try and reduce the slope...

Comment: @DaveInCaz This is a neat solution. Of course you could jack one floor up or lower the other - I know what I would consider...

Comment: @SolarMike I agree its a good solution, its just not really what I was asking. I could manufacture a shim if needed.

Comment: A gradual slope need not be visible since it is not a trip hazard. DIYing a shim like the one pictured is no simple task. Leaving a 3/4” transition is a trip hazard. I think any thing over 3/8” is a code issue.